# Load and Performance Testing of a Database

Tags: database, load-testing, performance-testing, stress-testing, database-testing

This is the first time, my team has asked me to do some testing on Database which I have no clue how to approach. By testing on database I mean, I need to see how fast it can insert records into it. And till what pressure it can handle. Just like Load and Performance Testing for database. The database that we are about to use is [XPRESSmp](http://www.ucirrus.com/#/xpressmp/4568626621).

So can anyone help me in what kind of testing we usually do when we need to Test the database and what are the tools that I can take a look into for this. Most of the articles that I have seen where mostly related to Oracle and MySQL. But this is a new database altogether.

One approach I can think of is write a Multithreaded Program with X number of threads that will pump the data into XMP at very high speed. And keep on measuring how much time each thread is taking. What else I can do to test the database?

My team has asked me to break the database by doing your testing but we should know at what situation it broked and what was the reason behind that.

And what important points I should know and take into the consideration while doing the testing on database.

P.S I will be doing this testing in seperate LnP machines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DB (SQL) automated stress/load tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887393/db-sql-automated-stress-load-tools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, SysBench is used to test queries performance on MySQL. It is not just for MySQL, though. I have only a basic knowledge of it, so I suggest you don't ask me and read documentation:
http://sysbench.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Replied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68438856/446317), use the [k6 SQL extension](https://github.com/imiric/xk6-sql).

Answer (score 1):

You can use these tools:

**HammerDB** is an open source database load testing and benchmarking tool for Oracle, SQL Server, TimesTen, PostgreSQL, Greenplum, Postgres Plus Advanced Server, MySQL and Redis. HammerDB is automated, multi-threaded and extensible with dynamic scripting support. HammerDB includes complete built-in workloads based on industry standard benchmarks as well as capture and replay for the Oracle database.

Download or see more information visit http://hammerora.sourceforge.net/

**p-unit**

Description:

An open source framework for unit test and performance benchmark, which was initiated by Andrew Zhang, under GPL license. p-unit supports to run the same tests with single thread or multi-threads, tracks memory and time consumption, and generates the result in the form of plain text, image or pdf file.
http://p-unit.sourceforge.net/

**DBMonster**

Description:

DBMonster is an application to generate random data for testing SQL database driven applications under heavy load. 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbmonster/